# mobile.changePage() not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

this is my code in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/kavin/5xVZQ/

what i want to get is when i click the image ,it should display options page and hide the image page , the image gets hid but the contents in the options page is not displayed , please help me , 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler and quick fix & no need of javascript code.

```
<a href='#options'> 
   <img id="option"  src="icons/options.png" width="80px" height="80px"/>  
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#option').click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#options'), 'pop');
        $('#option').hide();

    });
});​
```

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#option').click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage('#options', {transition:'pop'});
        $('#option').hide();

    });
});​
```

also if the click function doesn't work well, try using bind click instead. It happened to me once and when I used bind it worked.